# Algorithm to find all feasible partition of a set

Tags: combinatorics

By feasible I mean all the sets of the partition belongs to a predefined feasible sets.
For example, I what to find a partition of {1,2,3}, and only sets in S = {{1,2}, {1,3}, {1}, {2}, {3,4,5}} is allowed.

Any relevant literature is welcomed.

Comment: Of course we can eliminate any sets in $S$ that are empty or that are not subsets of the target, $T=\{1,2,3\}$ in your example. If $S$ were all of the nonempty subsets of $T$, the number of solutions you want to find is called [Bell's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions) $B_n$ where $n=|T|$.  Since generally there are so many of these to construct, I would guess that a backtracking algorithm (taking candidate subsets from $S$ in some predefined order) would perform adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the literature this is called the [Exact Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), and it is among [Karp's famous list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems) of 21 NP-complete problems.

Donald Knuth proposed [Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X) to solve it by formulating the available subsets as rows of a $\{0,1\}$-matrix, where the elements of the target set correspond to columns and $1$-entries to subsets whose row contains that element.  A solution is a subset of the rows that contains exactly one $1$ for each column. This approach uses recursion and backtracking to find all solutions, and features an algorithmic idea, [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links), that he credits to Hiroshi Hitotsumatsu and Kōhei Noshita.

Informally we would say to eliminate from the family $S$ of potential partitioning "cells" all but the nonempty subsets of the target $T$ to be covered.  Find an element $x$ of $T$ which appears the minimal number of times in our reduced $S$, and choose a set $C \in S$ such that $x \in C$.  (The fewer sets $C$ to choose from means the less backtracking we are apt to need. If there are no such sets containing $x$, we have failed and must backtrack if possible to examine other parts of the search tree.)

Now set $T' = T\backslash C$ and $S'$ to those sets in $S$ that are subsets of $T'$, i.e. disjoint from $C$.  Apply the algorithm recursively to obtain a partition of $T'$ using the candidates of $S'$.
Adjoining $C$ to the partition of $T'$, if one is found, gives a partition of $T$.

**Added:** Let's illustrate this approach using your example.  First we reduce $S$ by dropping the entry $\{3,4,5\}$ since it is not a subset of $T=\{1,2,3\}$ and so cannot form a cell of a partition.  Now $S = \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$.

Now $1$ is covered three times by $S$, $2$ is covered twice, and $3$ is covered only once.  Thus to cover $3$ we are forced to use set $\{1,3\}$ in our partition (exact cover) of $T$.

Define $T'=T\backslash \{1,3\} = \{2\}$, and define $S'$ to be those elements of $S$ that are subsets of $T'$ (or disjoint from $\{1,3\}$), i.e. $S' = \{\{2\}\}$.  Apply the algorithm to partition $T'$ using cells from $S'$.  Clearly the only choice is to take all of $T'=\{2\}$.

Thus the only solution for the example is the partition $\{1,2,3\} = \{1,3\} \cup \{2\}$.